# "Call to undefined function printer_open"

Tags: php, printing

I try to create a page that will print directly my images in php. I made on the internet and it seems that there are functions in php that can do that but I can not ENTERING these functions because apparently I do not have the extension installed php_printer now I ask for help to install this extension.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, 
you have to get this extension. 
After that you must put this inside your extension folder, it depends if you'are using wamp, lamp etc... After inserted your extension inside folder, you have to edit php.ini file. Search for extension entries inside the file and add a line:
extension=php_printer.dll

Comment: I did it but I do not have an extension that corresponds to my vesion of php is 5.3.13